# Android Fragment reset when replacing it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I'm currently developing a Android studio App using fragment and a bottom navigation bar. 
When I click on a navigation bar's item, it's replacing the current fragment by another one which correspond the fragment I wanted for this item.

The problem is, the objects in my fragment are all reset after replacing fragment.

I'm not removing the fragment from the container so I don't really understand why all the objects are reset after doing this.

Here is my code to add and replace fragment to my FrameLayout :

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_frame) == null) {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    }
    else
    {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

and here is the bottom navigation bar code to execute the previous function and change the displayed fragment:

```
homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
programFragment = new ProgramFragment();
bluetoothFragment = new BluetoothFragment();

mMainNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        test = mMainNav.getMenu().getItem(2);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                    //mMainNav.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
                HQ_logo_IV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setFragment(homeFragment);
                return true;

            case R.id.nav_program:
                    //mMainNav.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
                HQ_logo_IV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                setFragment(programFragment);
                return true;

            case R.id.nav_bluetooth:
                    //mMainNav.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                HQ_logo_IV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                setFragment(bluetoothFragment);
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Also i tried to add OnSaveInstanceState() and OnRestoreInstanceState() to save all the content of the fragment and restore it when the program initialize the fragment but it doesn't work either. It's making my app crash with this issue : `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to stop this thing.

I used an `AsyncTask` to refresh my fragment state.

I just put `new "yourAsyncTaskName"().execute()` at the beginning of my `onCreate()` method to refresh the fragment when it's created or replaced.

Hope this will help.